# Does space have to be allocated to ProcessStartInfo?

Tags: c#, memory-management, managed, processstartinfo

I am porting C++ code to C# and I came across this in the C++ code,

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shell;
memset(&shell, 0, sizeof(shell));
//the properties in shell are set
ShellExecuteEx(&shell);
```

So now I am using `Process.Start()` and `ProcessStartInfo` for the C# code. Do I have to allocate memory for `ProcessStartInfo` or is that done for me when I call the `ProcessStartInfo` constructor? And just for the sake for satiating my curiosity, is this way of using `memset` in C++ a practice of an unmanaged language or am I understanding something incorrectly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, memory it is allocated for you by .Net runtime env when you call constructor of your `ProcessStartInfo` obj with the keyword `new`.

This is the core meaning of the expression "managed .Net CLR languages".

The answer for your other question is: yes.

So called "unmanaged" languages as C++, or better all languages that as well as C++ have memory management in charge of developer and compilers of whom don't initialize allocated memory, have, after have instantiated or called object constructor, to initialize memory allocated otherwise its content will be dirty and could cause run time errors.

In your particular case, you are not calling a constructor, because you have a `struct` or value type variable, so the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO shell;` statement it is not a simple declaration but it is a real "*variable definition*", that is this statement causes a memory allocation.

Now, in C++ new allocated memory is always not initialized (instead "managed" languages have always allocated memory initialized) and so it is the developer to always initialize every new variables (value types or objects) when "*defined*" (that is allocated), and in C++ `memset` function does this.

So it is correct to think at the use you mentioned of `memset` in C++ as a best practice.

Comment: Thank you. This was a very thorough answer.

Answer (score 6):

As C# is a managed language, you will not have to provide memory explicitly when creating a `ProcessStartInfo` object.